# VS2010 automatic indents after typing for loop

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

In my VS2010, if I type a `for` loop somewhere in between blocks of code, VS will automatically indent the following line (or block) of code for me when I press the final semicolon (the one just before the iterator).

This is indescribably annoying as I very, very regularly type nested `for` loops in between existing blocks of code. I've gotten into the habit of automatically pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> right after the last semicolon so it undoes the indentation.

Is there any way I can turn this feature off?

Comment: Under Options -> Text Editor -> {Language of choice} -> Tabs.  Set the Indenting to "None".  That's my guess at least...

Comment: @sous2817 - Please post answers as *answers* rather than comments, so that people can up/downvote them, and mark them as accepted answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer:**

Tools → Options...  → Text Editor → C# → Formatting → Automatically format completed statement on ;

**Alternate answer:**

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> before typing the `for` loop. This command works from anywhere within a line, and inserts a new line above the current line and puts the cursor on the new empty line. When you press `;` at the end of your loop, the previous text will not be part of the line and will be unaffected by the automatic reformat.

Similarly, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> inserts a new line *below* the current line.

Comment: Amazing, thanks. Now I need to decide if I want to disable the auto-indent or use your alternate answer! :)

Answer (score -1):

Under Options -> Text Editor -> {Language of choice} -> Tabs. Set the Indenting to "None".